# How do I use uniqueId() jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It seems jquery ui is loaded because when i run

```
    $(function(){
      // did the UI load?
      console.log($.ui.version);
    });
```

the JS console returns 1.10.3

I am using the gem https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails (most recent)
and https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails version 2.1.4

I am trying to generate unique IDs for each youtube embed's iframe

```
$(".youtube_embed iframe").each.uniqueId();
```

am i doing it right?
I get this error in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( callback, args ) {
    return jQuery.each( this, callback, args );
} has no method 'uniqueId' 1:938
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: Functions have properties in JavaScript so `$(...).each.uniqueId()` is trying to call `uniqueId` on jQuery's [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) rather than on a jQuery object.

Comment: I suspect a lot of people landing on this question (or several of the similar/duplicate ones) might be grateful for this piece of information:

The function `uniqueId()` is not part of jQuery itself, but jQuery **UI**, see https://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should iterate each matching element and assign each element an unique id.

```
$(".youtube_embed iframe").each(function() {
    $(this).uniqueId();
});
```